# Open source "sci-fi"-like robot projects IRL

Tags: mobile-robot

I'm looking for a robot that is capable of moving around and has arms that can get objects in one place and drop in another. Something akin to what we see in most sci-fi movies, though much simpler. It may run on legs, wheels or tracks; it may have claws or hands. I'm looking for open-sourced design, schematics, specifications of the parts, coding - the whole package. It may be specific cases or projects/initiatives with a growing collection of robots.

As long as it can take out the trash, it's perfect. ;D

Comment: I don't expect this question to have lenghty explanation of current projects; instead, I expect it to list them, and be an on-going question where the most popular and current projects are added from time to time, as this is something that is progressing slowly (AFAIK). I shall accept the most concise answer, which will then be updated every now and then by the community, as some existing questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: Generally speaking, list questions like this tend to be a poor fit for a stack exchange site since they are often too localised to a specific moment in time. I will leave it for now, but as it stands it is a strong candidate for closure.

Comment: Remember, closure isn't necessarily permanent, if you can edit your question to be a better fit for the site, it can easily be re-opened.

Comment: Thank you Mark, I understand your point. If possible, I'd like to have something analogous to this:
http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese
Can you help me rephrase my question to make it suitable? (i.e., if you believe it is possible)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Open Source software for robots, check about the [ROS (robotics operating system)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Operating_System) from [willow garage](http://www.willowgarage.com/pages/software/ros-platform).

Comment: Note that *msb* was asking about *open source design* rather than open source *software* specifically.